# WorldWind Java API

Tags: java, maps, openstreetmap, worldwind

I want create a application that allows the user to enter longitude and latitude which is then shown on a map. I've come across [WorldWind](http://goworldwind.org/) but I've never heard of it before.

To create such application would I be better of using WorldWind or [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/)

As this is only one part of my application and Google maps won't allow the use of their maps on a desktop application, I wont be able to use Google maps.

Answer (score 2):

If you get latitude and longitude from user input, in WorldWind you can do:

```
    Position pos = new Position(Angle.fromDegreesLatitude(latitude), Angle.fromDegreesLongitude(longitude), altitude);
    PointPlacemark pp = new PointPlacemark(position);
    PointPlacemarkAttributes attrs = new PointPlacemarkAttributes();
    attrs.setImageAddress("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/red-circle.png");
    attrs.setScale(0.6);
    attrs.setImageOffset(new Offset(32d, 4d, AVKey.PIXELS, AVKey.PIXELS));
    pp.setAttributes(attrs);
    wwd.redraw();
```

By the way, you can use [Open Street Map layer](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.5/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/layers/Earth/OSMMapnikLayer.html) in World Wind.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use web, then use [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/) API.

[The code would be as simple as](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/10/25/integrating-google-maps-into-web-application.html):

```
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(-41.5, -187.5), 5);
```

Comment: Hi Suraj, thanks for your input. As the "map" is only one half of my project idea, I want to keep it all as a desktop application. I have tried to create a Java "Web browser" to resolve the issue with Google only allowing their maps to be used statically - But I couldn't get the browser to work with Javascript.

Comment: WorldWind has also a web base version. Check [NASAWorldWind/WebWorldWind project on gitbub](https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WebWorldWind). It has also [android version](https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindAndroid).

Answer (score 0):

For Desktop applications WorldWind is better, but u need to take care that all the client systems should have 3D capability Graphic cards.

Whereas if you are OK with Browser capability You can Try Google Maps.

Comment: WorldWind has also a web base version. Check [NASAWorldWind/WebWorldWind project on gitbub](https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WebWorldWind). It has also [android version](https://github.com/NASAWorldWind/WorldWindAndroid).